# Not receiving firebase notifications when the app is killed

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

After researching a lot, I have implemented the FCM correctly i.e i have used data payload instead of notifications. I have added the full code, Please tell me where I am making mistake?

MyFirebaseInstanceService:

```
package com.example.student.notitest.Service;

import android.app.Notification; import android.app.NotificationChannel; import android.app.NotificationManager; import android.content.Context; import android.graphics.Color; import android.os.Build; import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat; import android.util.Log;

import com.example.student.notitest.R; import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService; import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService; import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Map; import java.util.Random;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        if (remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty())
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        else
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    private void showNotification(Map<String, String> data) {


        String title = data.get("title").toString();
        String body = data.get("body").toString();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.student.notitest";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,"Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("Quiz App");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setTicker("India Quiz")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentInfo("info");
        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notificationBuilder.build());

    }

    private void showNotification(String title, String body) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.student.notitest";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,"Notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            notificationChannel.setDescription("India Quiz App Notifications Here");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setTicker("India Quiz")
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentInfo("info");
        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notificationBuilder.build());


    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);

        Log.d("TOKENFIREBASE",s);
    } }
```

I have also tried sending notifications via REST client, i.e ARC(google exension) but in vain. Please help as it has been more than 3 days coding on the same topic and yet not find any solution. 
Please please help!!

Comment: How do you kill your app?

Comment: Did you register the `FirebaseMessagingService` in the manifest file?

Comment: yes I have added @Jaymin

Comment: try to put some logger in `onMessageReceived`

Comment: Have you added `google-services.json` into your `app` module directory?

Comment: Also, `onMessageReceived()` will be called to handle a push notification **only** if your app process is alive. Otherwise a push notification will be handled by Android itself (a default notification with received title and message will be created in the status bar).